# Missing Wade's gang member in the end scene of "3:10 to Yuma"

Tags: character, 310-to-yuma

I just finished the movie [3:10 to Yuma (2007)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0381849/) and have some questions about Ben Wade's gang:

1. It was mentioned some time there was an Apache member in the gang. I do notice a guy with a black feather on the hat. He did show up during the scene where they split the money but why Charlie didn't mention his name to give his share?
2. When they all arrived at Contention, there were 7 of them, but in the end, I count only 6 shots when Wade killed them. I tried to id the kill and it looks like Jorgensen (the one with a bullet strap across his body) was missing. When was he killed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, about Jorgenson.

**[According to the script](http://www.cinefile.biz/script/yuma2010.pdf), Jorgenson is killed by Dan while he and Wade are in the store, just prior to their final run (across rooftops) to the train.**

**(This is scene 162D on pages 100 and 100A.)**

> DAN STRUGGGLES to regain control of the gun. As they thrash *
> A SHELF SPILLS. Suddenly, A LANTERN NEAR DAN’S HEAD EXPLODES *
> FROM GUNFIRE.

> From the store window, Jorgenson and Kinter try to pick off *
> Dan. Dan shoves Wade back and spins, taking a shot-- killing *
> Jorgenson and sending the rest for cover *

> DAN *
> We’re going to the train, Wade. *

> As Dan grabs at Wade, trying to drag him further, Wade just *
> stands there, unmoving. Dan pulls at him, as more shots ring. *
> Suddenly, Wade kicks out DAn’s good leg, sending him down the *
> steps into A STOCKROOM-- *

Then, about the Native American gang member,

**[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3:10_to_Yuma_(2007_film)), Wade's crew were:**

- Russell Crowe as Ben Wade, the ruthless leader of a band of outlaws, but who also has a strong sense of honor.
- Ben Foster as Charlie Prince, Ben's sadistic right-hand man, undyingly loyal to him.
- Rio Alexander as Campos, an outlaw and member of Wade's gang.
- Brian Duffy as Sutherland, an outlaw and member of Wade's gang.
- Pat Ricoti as Jorgensen, an outlaw and member of Wade's gang.
- Shawn Howell as Jackson, an outlaw and member of Wade's gang.
- Ramon Frank as Kinter, an outlaw and member of Wade's gang.
- Johnny Whitworth as Tommy Darden, an outlaw and member of Wade's gang.

So, yes, there were 7 in his gang, besides Wade himself. Funny enough, Nez is not listed.

**On Page 6, Scene 10, the gang is described,** and includes Nez.

> NEZ (32): An Apache renegade. He speaks little English and
> uses it rarely. But he is a great shot, a brilliant rider and
> a merciless fighter. He’s been with Wade since the beginning.

**Nez survives until Page 113, Scene 208:**

> 208 EXT. JAILHOUSE CABOOSE, TRAIN STATION - DAY

> Wade spins around on the last outlaw now... It’s Nez. Lining
> up on his boss. He hesitates when their eyes meet. And in
> that moment, Wade fires.

> Nez takes a blast to the chest but stays upright. He looks at
> Wade, sad. Wade shoots him again. And again. This is not easy
> for Wade. Finally, Nez topples.

> Wade turns, eyes filled with emotion, noticing--

> A mortally wounded Charlie Prince, pulling a pistol from dead
> Jorgensen’s holster.

> BAM, BAM, BAM-- Wade unloads his gun, putting an end to it.

**Another little bit of weirdness and I cannot explain,** is that [in IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0381849/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) it shows that two actors were credited with the part of Nez. So, the actor they used in the beginning scenes may not have been the same one from the end.

Comment: Wow, thank you for a detailed answer. Though I couldn't find the exact scene in the movie where Jorgensen is killed :( About Nez, it's weird that he doesn't get mentioned by name at all

Comment: Shrug, please remember that my answer is based on the script, not a transcript of the movie itself, which depends on the edits made during post-processing. There are often differences in the final edited version of a film as compared to the script. I hoped I would be able to answer what was supposed to be shown.